# Store subquery result as column alias for reuse

Tags: mysql, count, subquery

I am trying to create a column that contains counts, but the problem is where I go to reuse the subquery that does this the temporary table created previously becomes unavailable as it no longer exists.

My question is how can I store the result of a previous subquery so I can run something on that result later on in the same query?

First for the counts I have:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE _temp_unique_entity_manufacturers 
            (
              entityId INT(11),
              manufacturerRef INT(11),
              manufacturerName VARCHAR(255),
              KEY(entityId),
              KEY(manufacturerRef)
            )
            ENGINE=MEMORY AS 
              (SELECT DISTINCT entityRef AS entityId, manufacturer AS manufacturerRef, pm.name AS manufacturerName FROM enquiries, parts_trading, parts_manufacturers AS pm WHERE manufacturer = pm.id AND enquiryRef = enquiries.id)
```

And then in my main query I work with this table, specifically this part:

```
IF((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _temp_unique_entity_manufacturers WHERE entityId = eo.id) > 0,
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _temp_unique_entity_manufacturers WHERE entityId = eo.id),
   0
) AS manufacturers
```

The second subquery fails because the temp table is gone at this point. Is there a way where I dont have to write out the same subquery again and again?

Comment: Where does the `eo.id` come from in the subqueries??

Answer (score 0):

```
        case when
         ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _temp_unique_entity_manufacturers WHERE entityId = eo.id) > 0) then
           (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM _temp_unique_entity_manufacturers WHERE entityId = eo.id) else
           0 end
        ) AS manufacturers
    --------------
    ex:
    select coname,(case when cond then result else second result end) as user_colname from
    tablename
----------------------
If condition implement in sql as case when statement
```